How does GIL inserts the interupted thread and waiting threads back into the Ready Queue in Python?
Context:
I am executing the a python program that creates 5 threads as follows:
import time
from threading import Thread


def do_work(thread_number):
    print(f"Starting thread {thread_number}")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"Ending thread {thread_number}")


for i in range(5):
    t = Thread(target=do_work, args=(i,))
    t.start()

And I got the following outputs when I repeatedly observed the same program:
Output 1:
Starting thread 0
Starting thread 1
Starting thread 2
Starting thread 3
Starting thread 4
Ending thread 1
Ending thread 0
Ending thread 4
Ending thread 3
Ending thread 2

Ouput 2:
Starting thread 0
Starting thread 1
Starting thread 2
Starting thread 3
Starting thread 4
Ending thread 4
Ending thread 2
Ending thread 3
Ending thread 0
Ending thread 1

Output 3:
Starting thread 0
Starting thread 1
Starting thread 2
Starting thread 3
Starting thread 4
Ending thread 4
Ending thread 1
Ending thread 3
Ending thread 2
Ending thread 0

My Question:
It is clear from the output that the GIL in putting back the interupted thread at the last in the waiting queue.
And this is the reason why Started Thread <thread number> is getting printed first everytime before any Ending Thread <thread number>.
But since the threads are executed in order, i.e., first 0th, then 1st, then 2nd,.... then 4th, and if they are put back at the end of the Ready Queue, why aren't they ending in the same order?
What factors are changing this order?

The OS makes no promises which threads are woken up in which order. The OS also does not know anything about the GIL so it may wake up multiple threads at the same time on different cores, which will then race each other trying to acquire the GIL.

Related: The GIL used to be a simple mutex that gets released from time to time. Since python-3.2 it is a smarter system that ensures the mutex does not immediately return to the thread that released it. But which other thread gets it, is still up to the OS. This presentation summarizes it pretty well. However, that is separate from the scenario where multiple threads wake up and try to get the GIL at the same time


It is clear from the output that the GIL in putting back the interupted thread at the last in the waiting queue.

Nothing of the sort is true.
The GIL does not implement a wake queue, and Python does not implement the thread scheduler responsible for resuming your threads after sleeping.
Both of these are features of the underlying operating system.

why aren't they ending in the same order?

Even if all the threads are marked runnable in the same order they originally called sleep, there's no guarantee which will either resume execution, or produce output, first.
Your mental model might be correct on a bare-metal embedded system with co-operative threading, but on any modern system there's just a lot more going on when sleeping threads resume execution than you have taken into account.
